# Check new data in server from android without hitting to server

Tags: android, firebase, server

I want information there is new data in the server or not. So what I am doing, I am hitting the server in every 10 seconds and I am getting.

> what I want.
>
> I want just info is their new data in the server without hitting server.

Why I want to want

> If I hit the server for checking is there any new data this is decreasing my server performance.

What I search 
I have to made fire base notification so any new update I am getting a notification and based on notification I m hitting the server .
actually, this is I want but I   to send alert that I got new update .or is there any other tool and technology where I will hit and client get alerted so based on alert I will download new data.

> So I need similar this but better approach.
>   can any body suggest me any direction what to do ??
>   Thank for help advance

Comment: It can be accomplished of the clients register their ip each time their ip changes and listens to a particular port and the server sends notifications to that ip and port.

Comment: Google Cloud Message?

Comment: how to send i m using my mobile network or WiFi witch IP can we change any time

Comment: For this you have to implement websocket when ever there is change happen to server it will notify to app so there is dedicated connection required like firebase config do

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for, is the old style of getting data from a server. If you are looking for something like this, you can try to use a SQL Server but why would you need to verifiy for new data every 10 seconds, while Firebase does this in real time? When new data is added to your database, you are noticed, if nothing's new, nothing happens. I kindly recomand `Firebase` for what you need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i dont want from sql and i dont want to store data in database .i want some listener where any in data in sqldb i want notification or alert